# Security Vulnerability in Core Data Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sonarqube

I have an Objective-C application which uses Core Data. In Core Data Stack class, I used methods exactly as in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1).

In source code security analysis,

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

lines creating a vulnerability that must be solved to release the application. Report says, it is not secure to accessing a file by filename because in a jailbroken device, it can be manipulated.

Is it possible to initialize `NSManagedObject` different way or is it a false positive issue?

---

Security tool also show this kind of example when accessing and writing files securely:

```
NSString* fileNameTemplate = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"tmpfile-XXX.txt"];
const size_t bufLength = 2048;
 
char* fileNameBuf[bufLength];
strncpy(fileNameBuf, [fileNameTemplate cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], bufLength);
int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(fileNameBuf);
NSFileHandle* fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor];
NSString* stringToWrite = @"Hello world";
[fileHandle writeData: [stringToWrite dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: This seems like an overzealous vulnerability scanner. Unless you're building a banking or crypto app, there isn't much to gain from modifying most files in an app bundle.

Comment: That said, you could download the `momd` file from a server, put it in a local directory and read it from there, but unless you're doing that on launch, a jailbroken user can still modify that file.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, actually initializing with descriptor like in the example also not solving anything I guess. `momd` file still reachable and modifiable.

Comment: You can use `[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]`

Comment: Also you can use `NSPersistentContainer`

Comment: Changing this filename would be a useless attack because all it could do is install an incompatible model, preventing your app from loading any data. Might as well just crash the app because that’s what will happen anyway.

Comment: @TomHarrington I guess the attack scenario is not to change filename, maybe changing its contents. But persistent stores already encrypted on disk. So both scenarios leads to crash because of not loading any data.

Comment: Yes, and if the only effect is crashing the app, there are plenty of other ways to do that. Blocking this potential route doesn't help.